# Where does the change event come from and how to stop it in mat-selection-list

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using a `mat-selection-list` inside a `mat-menu` to filter some items. Whenever the menu gets closed, the selection list seems to trigger a `valueChanges` event on the form. How do I stop this?
Having the same with a menu and an input doesn't trigger `valueChanges` on menu closed.

```
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="m">Foo</button>
<mat-menu #m="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" [formGroup]="form">
  <ng-template matMenuContent>
    <mat-selection-list (click)="$event.stopPropagation();" formControlName="foo">
      <mat-list-option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of [1,2]">{{item}}</mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>

  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>

<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="m1">Foo1</button>
<mat-menu #m1="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" [formGroup]="form1">
  <ng-template matMenuContent>
    <input formControlName="foo1" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

---

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(e => {
  // gets triggered on menu close
  console.log('changed form', e);
});

this.form1.valueChanges.subscribe(e => {
  // doesn't get triggered on menu close
  console.log('changed form1', e);
})
```

Is there any way to stop the change event on close?

[Here's a playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-irxptr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)